# Copy all sheets from multiple workbooks to a single workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to select workbooks and to copy just sheet1 of all the workbooks to sheet1 of my Summary work book.

The problem is, I want to copy all the sheets from all the workbooks to my destination workbook.

Note that the sheet names on all the workbooks are identical.

Below is the code that I have.

```
Private Sub Merge_All_Click()

    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long


    ' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
    Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\ivan.emmanuel\Desktop\My Macro"

    ' Set the current directory to the the folder path.
    ChDrive FolderPath
    ChDir FolderPath

    ' Open the file dialog box and filter on Excel files, allowing multiple files
    ' to be selected.
    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

    ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
    NRow = 1

    ' Loop through the list of returned file names
    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        ' Set FileName to be the current workbook file name to open.
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)

        ' Open the current workbook.
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FileName)

        ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
        SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

        ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
        ' Modify this range for your workbooks. It can span multiple rows.
        LastRow = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                 After:=WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Range("A1"), _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
         Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:E" & LastRow)


        ' Set the destination range to start at column B and be the same size as the source range.
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False
    Next NFile

    ' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all data is readable.
    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: See [Loop Through all Sheets in all Files in a Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1144/loop-through-all-sheets-in-active-workbook/23038/loop-through-all-sheets-in-all-files-in-a-folder) and maybe brush up on your research skills.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, loop all worksheets in Workbook.

```
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim NFile As Long
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Sub merge()            

    ' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
    Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\ivan.emmanuel\Desktop\My Macro"

    ' Set the current directory to the the folder path.
    ChDrive FolderPath
    ChDir FolderPath

    ' Open the file dialog box and filter on Excel files, allowing multiple files
    ' to be selected.
    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
      filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

    ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
    NRow = 1

    ' Loop through the list of returned file names
    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        ' Set FileName to be the current workbook file name to open.
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)

        ' Open the current workbook.
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FileName)

        ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
        SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

        ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
        ' Modify this range for your workbooks. It can span multiple rows.
        LastRow = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                 After:=WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Range("A1"), _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

    Dim ws As Worksheet                '---------added to for copy from all worksheets
    For Each ws In Workbook            '--------

        Set SourceRange = ws.Range("A1:E" & LastRow)  '------------

        ' Set the destination range to start at column B and 
        '  be the same size as the source range.
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
          SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

    Next                               '------------

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False
Next NFile

' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all data is readable.
SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```